# Using Facebook & Twitter API's on the same local deployment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-php-sdk, twitter-oauth

I am trying to build an application on my local machine using Twitter's OAuth 1.1 API and Facebooks SDK v4 both for PHP.

Both of these mechanisms redirect the user to prompt for permission and redirect back to website. I can get both working but they will not work under the same local url.

I set everything up for Facebook on localhost without any issues but twitter (staggeringly) does not allow using localhost (see here [How to test the twitter API locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726695/how-to-test-the-twitter-api-locally)). So instead I set up a virtual host using my Mac based MAMP installation and added that url to both Twitter and Facebook applications. Now Facebook does not allow me to use my virtual host. When the prompt for permissions happens and Facebook redirects back to my site, when  I try and retrieve the session using getSessionFromRedirect() it returns NULL. This does not happen if I run the same code using localhost.

I have tried using 127.0.0.1 but Facebook does not allow this either (error is invalid because it is a Facebook url!), but Twitter does!?!

Has anyone else had any problems with this or does anyone have any pointers that would help me to test both of these on the same deployment.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So put some domain name in `/etc/hosts` and specify it in facebook?

Comment: That is what MAMP does! It automatically adds the virtual domain to your /etc/hosts file...

Comment: So what is the problem then?

Comment: When the permissions are accepted and it redirects the browser, the getSessionFromRedirect() method returns NULL. This does not happen when using localhost. Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: what you just explained isn't in the original question. In the original question you only have issues with the domain name. Could you please change the question so that it reflected your **REAL** issue?

Comment: The reason why I am asking about my local domain is that I am currently unable to use both Twitter and Facebook API's together with one local domain so I think my question is relevant as if both allowed me to use localhost then I would not need to worry about setting a virtual host to please both API's. I have updated the question to include the problem I am having with Facebook.

Comment: there is no reason to use "localhost". Use **ANY** domain name you like - there is no difference.

Comment: Facebook does not allow for me to use my virtual domain in the PHP SDK  so how can I use any local virtual domain that I like?

Comment: they allow to use any domain that looks like "real". Create neilyoung.com and it will accept it.

Comment: Looks like this is a recent change at facebook, as i set up an app about 3 months ago and they allowed `127.0.0.1` then. I've just changed my 'site url' to test a different local ip and am now unable to change it back...